# How To Host Root Domain In Blogger and Subfolder In Bluehost

Tags: wordpress, dns, hosting, blogger

I have successfully hosted my root domain name i.e www.domain.com in google blogger by adding CNAME records but now i want to host my domain subfolder i.e www.domain.com/folder on wordpress with bluehost.

Is this possible ?

PS: I have updated Correct NameServers with my bluehost

Thanks

Comment: yes and no. blogger doesn't let you control your virtualhost or htaccess so chances is slim.